# Is method without async returning value using Task.Run a bad practice?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I don't see this patter used very often so it makes me wonder is there something wrong with the following approach?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetText());
        }
    }

    public static string GetText()
    {
        string result = "";
        Task.Run(() => result = Environment.TickCount.ToString()).Wait();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Also, could someone please explain why I get a "not all paths return value" compiler error with:

```
    public static string GetText()
    {           
        Task.Run(() => { return Environment.TickCount.ToString();  }).Wait();            
    }
```

Comment: you need to read some basics before you jump into multi threading. that's not quite right. (I'm assuming that you are beginner because other wise you wouldn't ask your second question.)

Comment: The return needs to be after the Wait().  So return Task.Run(() => { yield Environment.TickCount.ToString();  }).Wait();

Comment: `Task.Run(...).Wait();` just means you want to block 2 threads instead of one.

Comment: Tasks don't necessarily use a 2nd thread. It will probably just run on the main thread

Comment: @JoePhillips `Task.Run` always uses the thread pool task scheduler so it will always run on a 2nd thread. `Task.Factory.StartNew` [depending on the situation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) could end up doing the task on the UI thread.

Comment: @JoePhillips Tasks in general don't necessarily use another thread, but the code shown here does.

Comment: Got it. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't see this pattern very often is because it does nothing. You are creating tasks to run on separate threads, but you are also immediately asking your main thread to wait for the other thread to finish. There's no value there. The point of multi-threading is for the calling thread to keep going while the other threads do other work.

For your 2nd question: Your return statement exists within the lambda you provided (a lambda is the () => {} notation). When you call Task.Run, you are telling the compiler "Start a new thread and when the thread is ready to go, execute the code I'm about to give you". The lambda is the code that should execute in the other thread. It doesn't get executed in the thread that called Task.Run. As far as GetText() is concerned, you never called return, and you never returned a value. This is why the compiler is telling you there's a problem.